# setOnItemClickListener не срабатывает

Tags: android, listview

Всем привет. Помогите понять причину несрабатывания setOnItemClickListener'a. 
Код следующий:
Layout файл для Активити в который будем добавлять Item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="Add" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Список Матеріалів"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout2" />
```

Layout самого Item'a

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="MAt"
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text=""
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView13"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Id"
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView14"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Load"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

И сам код Activity

```
public class materialListofDraft extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
ListView listView;
Button btnAddNewMaterial;
ArrayList<Integer> idMaterials;
long orderPosition;
private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
//MyTask task;
ArrayList<String> materialimageFilenames = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
        LocalInfo.getOrders().size());
Map<String, Object> m;
final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_MATERIAL_NAME = "MATERIALNAME";
final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_COUNT_DETAIL = "COUNT";
final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_MATERIAL_ID = "ID";
final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE_NAME = "IMAGE";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_material_listof_draft);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    btnAddNewMaterial = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btnAddNewMaterial.setOnClickListener(this);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    for (int i = 0; i < LocalInfo.getMaterialsStructureOfOrders().size(); i++) {
        materialimageFilenames.add(LocalInfo.getMaterialsStructureOfOrders().get(i).getMaterail().getImageLarge());
        m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_MATERIAL_NAME, LocalInfo.getMaterialsStructureOfOrders().get(i).getMaterail().getName());
        m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_COUNT_DETAIL, LocalInfo.getMaterialsStructureOfOrders().get(i).getIdDetails().size());
        m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_MATERIAL_ID, LocalInfo.getMaterialsStructureOfOrders().get(i).getMaterail().getId());
        m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE_NAME, R.mipmap.page404);
        data.add(m);
    }
    String[] from = {ATTRIBUTE_NAME_MATERIAL_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_NAME_COUNT_DETAIL,
            ATTRIBUTE_NAME_MATERIAL_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE_NAME};
    int[] to = {R.id.textView12, R.id.textView13, R.id.textView14, R.id.imageView};
    simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.unitlist_material, from, to);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case (R.id.button4): {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, materialtemplates.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data1) {
    // запишем в лог значения requestCode и resultCode
    Log.d("myLogs", "requestCode = " + requestCode + ", resultCode = " + resultCode);
    // если пришло ОК
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Ok result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Log.v("asdfasdf", "asdfasdf");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Tatta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

При этом грешу в сторону Layout файлов, поскольку onItemClick() в других Activity срабатывал нормально, а здесь нет :(

Comment: Поскольку OnClickListener устанавливается исключителньо на кнопку, нет смысла проверять id нажатой View. Убери эту проверку и МБ заработает

Comment: С OnClickListener все нормально. Дело в setOnItemClickListener для ListView, точнее для Item'ов которые ему закидываю

Comment: Попробуйте объявить анонимный класс AdapterView.OnItemClickListener непосредственно в методе  listView.setOnItemClickListener, а не интерфейсом класса, будет ли работать так?

Comment: Анонимно - несработало :(. Первым делом пробывал. Уточню: button4 - здесь непричом , у него другая задача. А button в самом Item - покачто не реализован - но это совсем другая история :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Активная кнопка на элементе списка мешает, выставьте ей атрибуты вот так:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

        android:text="Load"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />
```

Comment: извеняюсь. но если использовать этот прийом при варианте что вместо кнопки ТРИ `TextView (EditText,Numeric)` + registerForContextMenu(listView) для менюшек по каждому `Item` - несрабатывает. `android:textIsSelectable="true"` также непомог. - Или здесь другой принцип?

Comment: Не понял вас, может новый вопрос создадите?