# Не срабатывает setOnItemClickListener для нажатия кнопки редактирования записи

Tags: android, kotlin, button, setonclicklistener

Задача: по нажатию кнопки в элементе ListView должна открываться Activity где в дальнейшем будет редактироваться запись. Проблема в том, что все перепробованные мной методы на похожие проблемы не работают, сейчас остановился на setOnItemClickListener, но суть в том, что он не срабатывает ни каким образом. Т.е даже лог не выводит. Что делать не знаю, битый час сижу

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
var myListView: ListView? = null
var db: MainDB? = null
var dao: Dao? = null
var csr: Cursor? = null
var sca: SimpleCursorAdapter? = null
var btn_edit1: ImageButton?= null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //binding = MainActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
    myListView = findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    db = MainDB.getDB(this)
    dao = db!!.getDao()
    /*
    val p1 = Item(null,null,null,null,null)
    p1.plant_description = "Ромашка"
    p1.plant_room = "комната"
    p1.plant_send_push = true
    p1.plant_time_to_watering = 24
    dao!!.insertItem(p1)
    */
    Log.e("LOG","KJFKJFJFKJFKFKKF")

    btn_edit1 = this.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btn_edit)

    myListView!!.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
        val buttonEdit = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btn_edit)
        Log.e("LOG","НАЖАТИЕ ЕСТЬ")
        buttonEdit.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, ItemActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("Range")
private fun setUpOrRefreshListView() {
    csr = getCursor()
    if (sca == null) {
        sca = SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.row_item,
            csr,
            arrayOf<String>("plant_description","plant_time_to_watering","plant_room","plant_send_push"),
            intArrayOf(R.id.plant_description,R.id.plant_time_to_watering,R.id.plant_room,R.id.plant_send_push),
            0
        )

        myListView!!.adapter = sca

    } else {
        sca!!.swapCursor(csr)
    }
}
private fun getCursor(): Cursor {
    val plants: List<Item> = dao!!.getAllItem()
    val mxcsr = MatrixCursor(
        arrayOf(
            BaseColumns._ID,
            "plant_description",
            "plant_time_to_watering",
            "plant_room",
            "plant_send_push"
        ),
        0
    )
    //dao!!.getAllItem() // plants
    for (p in plants) {
        mxcsr.addRow(arrayOf<Any>(p.id.toString(),
            p.plant_description.toString(),
            p.plant_time_to_watering.toString(),
            p.plant_room.toString(),
            p.plant_send_push.toString()))
    }
    return mxcsr
}

/* If resuming this activity then refresh the ListView */
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    setUpOrRefreshListView()
}

/* if the activity is detsroyed then close the Cursor */
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    csr!!.close()
}
```

}

Элемент списка

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:elevation="2dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/plant_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imagepng"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="top">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3sp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/plant_description"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                android:text="kfkpomremkremmrpeomvpremvopporvmpormolmlmlllmlmlmlmllmmlmlllmmlmlmlmpvreoprevmporeovmeopvmepovmrepovmevpoem"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
                android:maxLength="100">
            </TextView>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:foreground="@drawable/edit_button"
                    android:drawableTint="@color/white"
                    android:drawableTintMode="multiply"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_ripple_button"
                    android:padding="5dp"/>
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/plant_send_push"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:focusable="false"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1sp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                android:text="Поливать каждые:">
            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/plant_time_to_watering"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                android:text="24ч"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart">
            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/plant_room"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                android:text="Кухня"
                android:maxLength="18"
                android:textAlignment="center">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/537463/11515 - не ваш случай?

Comment: Нет, уже смотрел это

Comment: Сначала адаптер присваивается, а потом слушатель.

Comment: @MubaraksaGen, что смотрели? У вас в разметке элемента две кнопки и у них нет атрибутов выключения фокуса, которые советуют в том ответе. Либо забудьте про обработчик элемента и вешайте обработчики непосредственно на кнопки в адаптере. И лучше используйте `RecyclerView`.  `Listview` стоит использовать только для примитивных списков (у которых разметка один `TextView`)

Comment: Да, ошибка была в этом, просто не предполагал, что чекбоксу так же нужно поставить атрибуты. В любом случае проект просто чтобы по нему отчет написать и забыть. Переписал все на java с sqlite, на котором мне понятнее, там та же проблема была. Поставил другой шаблон записи с 1 текстовым полем и он заработал, тогда и дошло, что проблема не в коде, а в разметке.